# CCGLView Blank in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCGLView which is created in Interface Builder. I have a root Navigation Controler onto which I'm pushing a custom UIViewController. When this UIViewController loads, I wire up my CCGLView in viewDidLoad, and everything works - I can interact with my scene.

When I pop my viewcontroller with the back button, then attempt to load it again, the space where my scene should appears just black. Am I missing something?

This is how I set the scene and view for the director:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
[director setView:glView]; // glView declared/typed in IB

CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
[scene setContentSize:self.glView.frame.size];
scene.position = ccp(0,0);

self.storySceneLayer = [StorySceneLayer node];  // Create the scene that contains our game world
self.storySceneLayer.delegate  = self;
[scene addChild: self.storySceneLayer];

[director pushScene:scene];
[director runWithScene:scene];
[director startAnimation];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to another issue, to which @gmogames posted a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11077131/30512