# Restarting cocos2d's scene from UIKit Menu

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uikit

i have a UIKit menu based on UIButtons, when i click on one of them i'm firing a cocos2D scene. i'm setting up the CCDirector in the AppDelegate :

```
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
[director setDisplayFPS:YES];
[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];
```

and in the rootViewController (the viewController that will holds my EAGLView) i'm doing this in the viewDidLoad method :

```
 glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:self.view.bounds
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    
                               depthFormat:0 

                    ];

glView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view insertSubview:glView atIndex:0];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setOpenGLView:glView];
CCScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithParent:self];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
```

i'm setting up my menu in the MainMenuViewController, from where i push the RootViewController in the stack of a navigationController. This works perfectly and my game starts without problems. I can also go back with a UIButton from the RootViewController (which holds the cocos2d scene) : `- (IBAction)goBack { 
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];}`

but when i try to reload my game scene the application quit. i've tried this method : 
 [restart CCDirector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037134/cocos2d-2-0-rc2-end-the-director-and-restart?rq=1) but in vain!! i've tried to pause the CCDirector and restart animation but also in vain, the error that i'm getting is in relation with the draw method of cocos2d!! 
please help

Answer (score 0):

i've just solved my problem. so if you are trying to use a UINavigationController you don't have to use `[[CCDirector sharedDirector] end]`, because when the rootController is poped from the stack, all the scenes of cocos2d world will be released. But if you are trying to removing only the subview (not the hole controller) you have to end the CCDirector!! my problem was in a singleton class that i added as a child of GameScene, when i ended the CCDirector it still exists in the memory so i had to release it before recreating the game scene..hope this was clear.